# How to remove post submit restrictions? NodeBB

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodebb

I need remove composer textfield, and i can remove this from the composer.tpl in my plugin, but where i try submit the topic, the NodeBB sendme a notification says: Please enter a longer post. Posts should contain at least 8 character(s).

How i can disable this verifications via my plugin?

Comment: Cheat: Mark the field hidden and set the value to 8 spaces?

Comment: I already tried that, but this not work because the validator script not assuming spaces as characters.